# Verificar se registro já existe (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7, codeigniter-3

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para agendamentos(setor automotivo).
A ideia é o usuário escolher um instalador(`ComboBox`), Horário(`ComboBox`) esses horários já são pré-definidos e a Data(`Input`/`Date`).

Estou tentando criar uma condição em que, se o instalador já tiver agendamento naquela data e horário, não exista a possibilidade de agendar novamente(Duplicar), e exibir uma mensagem de aviso.

CONTROLLER:

```
$dados = array(
                'tecAg' => $this->input->post('tecAg'),
                'horaAgIns' => $this->input->post('horaAgIns'),
                'data' => $this->input->post('data')
            );

            $this->load->model('agendamentos_model');

             if(!$this->agendamentos_model->verifica($dados['horaAgIns' && 'tecAg' && 'data'])) {

                echo 'Horário já utilizado!'; 

                } else {

                $data = array(
                    'tecAg' => set_value('tecAg'),
                    'horaAg' => set_value('horaAg'),
                    'data' => set_value('data'),
```

MODEL:

```
public function verifica($tecAg, $horaAgIns, $data){
    $this->db->where('tecAg', $tecAg);
    $this->db->where('horaAgIns', $horaAgIns);
    $this->db->where('data', $data);

    return $this->db->get('agendamentos')->row_array();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilizar essa biblioteca de select do Codeigniter dificulta muito na minha opinião, tente o seguinte :

Para começar coloque essa linha de código no construct do seu controller

```
$this->load->model('agendamentos_model','agendamentos');
```

Para poder utilizar mais facilmetne o seu model no controller, somente o chamando como **"agendamentos"**

Agora vamos ao seu problema, ao meu ver, você pode simplesmente colocar desta maneira, sem fazer verificações antes de se o agendamento ja existe, apenas faça o insert utilizando o **on conflict**:

```
$sql = "insert into tabela_agendamento(tecAg, horaAgIns, data) 
values (?, ?, ?) on conflict(data) do nothing";
```

No insert acima (Por favor mude o nome da tabela para o correto, a parte do codigo "on conflict", diz que se algum registro já existir com a mesma data, ele não vai inserir o registro, agora basta executar.

```
$this->db->insert($sql, [$tecAg, $horaAgIns, $data]);
```

Caso não utilize o $this->db, basta habilitar nas libraries em **application/config/autoload.php** colocando **'database'** dentro do array de **$autoload['libraries']**.

Comment: Primeiramente, muito obrigado pela reposta VitorZF.

Comment: A minha ideia é que esses três campos(tecAg, horaAgIns, data) recebam esse dados via input do formulário e faça essa consulta no banco antes de gravar os registros, existem mais campos no formulário mas a ideia era só deixar gravar se esses horários estiverem disponíveis.
Já existe uma função Adicionar().
Por isso tentei utilizar um If dentro desta mesma função.
@VitorZF

Comment: No caso você pode fazer desta maneira, https://repl.it/repls/GhostwhiteColdWorkplace

Comment: Consegui aqui, utilizando um IF mesmo, era só a lógica que estava errada.
Muito obrigado pela força @VitorZF